# Running a Node.js script between certain hours everyday

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am trying to run a Javascript file everyday specifically between 9 am and 5 pm and I was wondering if there is a proper way to do it using cron or some other method. At 5 pm, I would like the running script to be ended as if I hit ctrl-c in the terminal. The following morning, it would automatically restart.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by dividing the task into two steps

> 1. A [cron](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crontab-in-linux-with-examples/) job is to be scheduled that starts the node procces everyday at 9AM. For that suppose you have a node file named **script.js** and it's location is **/home/user/example/script.js** then the following command will be used to run it everyday at **9AM daily**

```
* 9 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/example/script.js
```

> 2. Now to close the script everyday a 5PM, this can be done **implicitly** using [setTimeout](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-exit-in-node-js/) function.Below is the code to be written in **script.js**

```
setTimeout((function() {
return process.exit(1);}), 28,8000,000);//28,8000,000 Milliseconds
```

**This way the script.js will start it's execution daily at 9AM and stop at 5PM.**

Comment: You shouldn't put commas in the milliseconds, as it will be read as multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a systemd service file for your script [like this](https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/) then  you can use cron to start and stop the service at the required times.